# Locked myself out at the waterfall location

Tags: the-witness

I was just curious what

> that switch would do and just used it.

Now I cannot enter that location anymore and also I can't find any switch to roll back that action.

> [image]

Is there any chance for me to get inside?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That switch is part of the tropical-forest puzzle progression.  The other side of that panel contains more puzzles.  There is no way to bring it down, you need to walk to the other side of it.

You can doing this by taking the path on the right, which leads down to the temple area.  Two more lefts will lead to the entrance of the tropical forest, and another immediate left leads to those puzzles.

---

**[Edit]** Another way to get there, by request:  Exit the temple out the back entrance, facing the ocean.  Walk down the steps, then turn left to enter the jungle forest.  Go up the stairs at the next left, and follow that path.

Another alternate method:  Climb the mountain, then climb down at the beach.  Follow the beach until it turns into the forest, then take the last right.

Comment: Unfortunately I cant figure out how to to get there. Do you mean that path? http://i.imgur.com/OlC36SH.jpg That path doesn't lead anywhere I suppose. If I go down I see 2 doors: the one for the temple area and another one leading down.

Comment: @DannyLo: See edit.

Comment: Oh gosh, how could I have missed that area! Now I also see that I actually needed to activate that switch ;)