# I beat the game. It reset my progress. What gives?

Tags: the-witness

I unlocked several of the (evidently optional) secrets, and I was definitely expecting to be able to go back and continue working toward completing the game.

However, when I finished the game,

> I get flown back into the starting chamber

And all of my progress appears to be completely be wiped out and I would have to re-play hundreds of puzzles just to even get back to all of the areas in the game again.

This strikes me as being so completely wrong that I'm wondering if it is a bug or not. Maybe there's a menu option or something that I missed.

At any rate, I'm hoping that somewhere in my Steam cloud progress data there is a way for me to go back so that I can actually continue my game without actually re-playing it.

Comment: This may be a complete duplicate because this answer seems to address my concern. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/257493/12407 So although it seems like I should have a "safe" savegame I can restore to continue playing the game without going to the point of no return, I really do not understand the design decision to make it work this way at all.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what your specific question is... if you're asking why the game was designed that way, that's a "developer intent" question that is off-topic for the site. If you think your question is a duplicate, you can either flag the question as a dupe or just delete it. Or, if your question is something else, please clarify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not a bug, it's intentional.

Fortunately, you don't need to start the game over - **the game creates a save-point just before the ending.**  Just load up that save, and you're good to go.

> The game's not over yet!

Comment: Now that i am back to checking out if there is more content in this game now that 2016 is over, and at least 2016 gave us this nice game, right? Boy that ending sequence really had me freaking out because I knew there was more content and more unsolved puzzles. So the savegame is me in the elevator, and it seems like I do have to "undo" a few puzzles to climb myself back out of the tower to get back to the rest of the land to finish solving everything. Hopefully I'm on the right track now.

Comment: Just in case anyone else was in the same situation I was– my game saved in the closed elevator, right before the end sequence. To exit the closed elevator, there’s a puzzle control for each door at the *bottom* of each door, rather than at the top!

Comment: Agree. There is not a point of no return in this game. Save points are created prior to the ending sequence, and you can always pick up where you left off.