# Possible to Accidentally Block the End Game Area?

Tags: the-witness

This question involves major spoilers for The Witness. You won't even be able to understand the question unless you've completed one particular environmental puzzle (in the mountain) and have found the entrance to the caves.

I am near 100% completion of The Witness, but I believe I may have accidentally blocked off access to an area of the game, specifically the end game area. I want to see if anyone else has had this problem or knows how to get out of it.

So first, I got this environmental puzzle: http://www.ign.com/wikis/the-witness/File%3ALevel3.png

Then, when I got to the bottom, I exited by going through the cave network, which means that the big stone door closed behind me.

Later, I was going back through the mountain to look for audio logs, and I realized that I enter the level with that environmental puzzle on the side of the blue path, which now goes nowhere. I can't make it exit the area, and I can't make it give me access to the other side.

So now it seems like I can't get past that level. Is that right? If so, it would be very unfortunate.

Comment: IIRC there's a panel to open the stone door from the inside (temporarily).

Comment: The image link is dead, can you correct it?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't. I don't even really remember what I was referencing there. I know it was one of the puzzles inside the mountain where you are drawing the path that you'll walk on. I believe that in order to get an environmental puzzle that you find by looking up at the path from below it, you have to set that path in such a way that it can only be accessed from the side that leads down into the mountain, not up. As a result, if you circle back around, you won't be able to go down any farther past it.

Comment: Similar: [Locked myself out at the waterfall location](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/253950/74546).

Answer (score 6):

There's a panel to open the stone door again from inside the cave. None of the other exits from the cave area close automatically, so you can go back in whichever exit you used (probably the one near the color swamp). Remember to go and fix the middle level of the mountain so you can get through there easily again!